# Drupal ajax load and submit form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm developing a site with Drupal, and I'm learning a lot about this framework?, CMS? (I don't know xD)...

I read a lot about ajax load forms and ajax submit form in Drupal but I don't like information I've seen:

### Load Ajax Form:

The way I load a form via Ajax is by hooking_menu in my module. But there is some issues to do this fine. I need to create another empty-css theme on drupal to load this form correctly (if not main theme will be loaded (page.tpl.php design) ). My hook_menu:

```
$items['vaccination/%bv_children/%bv_vacunas'] = array(
    'title' => 'Añadir Vacunación',
    'file' => 'includes/vacunas.inc',
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in',
    'page callback' => 'bv_vaccination_form_view',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
    'theme callback' => array('bebevax_cartilla_e_name_theme')
);
```

'theme callback' returns name of "empty-css" theme for loading this form with no styles, no html headers, etc. 
The way I "call" this form is by javascript:

```
$('.form-popup').load('vaccination/'+child_id+'/'+vaccination_id);
```

It takes so much time to load entirely because a lot of files (css, more js, etc) are loaded.

Anybody knows about load ajax form and load It correctly? I don't think that this is the best  way to do this...

I need some guides or tutos for load ajax form...

### Submitting Ajax load form

The other side of the picture is submit this kind of forms... How can I "catch" (overload) submit javascript handler? I need to write some form values into my HTML.

Thank you for all your support...

xD

Comment: Take a look at this post. It should do what you want: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/loading-a-form-via-ajax-with-drupal-get-form

Comment: Not bad, but how can I submit this form via ajax too??? That thread does not answer that... any better solution?